# How to match regular expression starting exactly at a given index?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

With the .NET [`Regex` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex), is there any way to match a regular expression inside a string *only* if the match starts exactly at a specific character index?

Let's look at an example:

- regular expression `ab`
- input string: `ababab`

Now, I can search for matches for the regular expression (named `expr` in the following) in the input string, for instance, starting at character index `2`:

```
var match = expr.Match("ababab", 2);
//  match ------------->XXab
```

This will be successful and return a match at index `2`.

If I pass index `1`, this will *also* be successful, pointing to the same occurrence as above:

```
var match = expr.Match("ababab", 1);
//  match ------------->X ab
```

**Is there any efficient way to have the second test fail, because the match does not start *exactly* at the specified index?**

Obviously, there are some work-arounds to this.
As my string in which testing occurs might be ... "long" (think possibly 4 digit numbers of characters), I would, however, prefer to avoid the overhead that would presumably occur in all three cases one way or another:

| # | Work-Around | Drawback |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I could check the resulting match to see whether its `Index` property matches the supplied index. | Matching throughout the entire string would still take place, at least until the first match is found (or the end of the string is reached). |
| 2 | I could prepend the start anchor `^` to my regular expression and always test just the substring starting at the specified index. | As the string may be very long and I might be testing the same regex on multiple starting positions (but, again, only *exactly* on these), I am concerned about performance drawbacks from the frequent partial copying of the long string. (Ranges might be a way out here, but unfortunately, the `Regex` class cannot (yet?) be used to scan them.) |
| 3 | I could prepend `"^.{#}"` (with `#` being replaced with the character index to test) for each expression and match from the beginning, then fish out the actually interesting match with a capturing group. | I need to test the same regex on multiple possible start positions throughout my input string. As each time, the number of skipped characters changes, that would mean compiling a new regex every time, rather than re-using the one that I have, which again feels somewhat unclean. |

Lastly, the `Match` overload that accepts a maximum length to check in addition to the start index does not seem useful, as in my case, the regular expression is not fixed and may well include variable-length portions, so I have no idea about the expected length of a match in advance.

Comment: I guess you could use a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`(?<=^..)ab`](https://regex101.com/r/Q7v01k/1)

Comment: If all you care about is pass/fail, then anchor your query to the beginning of the string with `^` and `.{2}`, where the 2 is your desired index.  So, `^.{2}ab`  will ensure that a and b only match in the 3rd and 4th positions.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Thanks, that's a good idea for work-around 3. It doesn't change anything about the performance concern I had (see added details in question), but at least it avoids added confusion by additional capturing groups.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer: That seems to be what I outlined as work-around 3 in the question. Though, no, pass/fail is not enough; I also need the exact length of the total matched portion, and the regex itself might contain any number of named capturing groups that I'm already working with.

Comment: I think what comes close to your requirements is [`\K` which resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match. But unfortunately this is not available in .NET regex. ([PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7uGVL/1))

Comment: @bobblebubble: Well, that page says *"The key difference between `\K` and a lookbehind is that in PCRE, a lookbehind does not allow you to use quantifiers: the length of what you look for must be fixed"*. But as far as I can tell, the .NET implementation of RegEx lookbehinds does not have that restriction - e.g. `(?<=c.*)cd` is a valid use of lookbehinds in .NET. (That notwithstanding, I was meanwhile pointed to the `\G` anchor in an answer, and combined that with your initial suggestion to use a lookbehind, which appears to work well. Thank you :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can use the `\G` operator, `\Gab` pattern will allow you to match at the second index and will fail at the first one, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/HwcIOU):

```cs
Regex expr = new Regex(@"\Gab");
Console.WriteLine(expr.Match("ababab", 1)?.Success); // => False
        
Regex expr2 = new Regex(@"\Gab");
Console.WriteLine(expr2.Match("ababab", 2)?.Success); // => True
```

As per the documentation, [`\G` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) matches like this:

> The match must occur at the point where the previous match ended, or if there was no previous match, **at the position in the string where matching started**."

Comment: This looks very good - placing that `\G` anchor into a positive lookbehind as was [suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026057?noredirect=1#comment132398770_75026057) seems to yield the desired result. Thank you, I think I read the docs for that anchor without realizing what it actually means in context.